# How to detect terminal enter in vim8

Tags: terminal

Vim8 now has a terminal feature, how can I detect when a terminal is started?

Neovim has `TermOpen` and `TermClose` autocommand events, does vim8 has an equivalent?

Comment: What is terminal enter?

Comment: I don't think you can (yet). Remember that terminal support in Vim is highly experimental at the moment; as `:help terminal.txt` notes: `WARNING: THIS IS ONLY PARTLY IMPLEMENTED, ANYTHING CAN STILL CHANGE`. That being said, you could maybe use `BufEnter` or `WinEnter` and check `buftype`?

Comment: Why do you need this? Isn't a BufEnter/WinEnter autocommand enough?

Comment: autocmd WinEnter or BufEnter not work

Comment: @tracyone cannot reproduce. BufEnter autocommands are triggered when entering the terminal. so works as expected

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt hi, autocmd BufEnter * if &buftype=="terminal" |   echom "Enter terminal" | endif, It is not work at the first time create a new terminal buffer.

Comment: true. That is a bug I also noticed. That is a bug, that should probably be reported to vim-dev and will be fixed **hint** note, you could currently test for bufname starting with '!' or so. However, it does not mean, that BufEnter autocommand does not work.